# Vue.js with Rollup.js renders html comment instead of Vue html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rollupjs

Recently started working with Vue.js and am having difficulties getting a simple interpolation to render inside of my local development app.

**The Output**

- For some reason, the Vue instance renders an html comment of `createElement`

```
<body>
  <script id="__bs_script__">
    //<![CDATA[
    document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.26.7'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
    //]]>
  </script>
  <script async="" src="/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.26.7"></script>

  <!--function (a, b, c, d) { return createElement(vm, a, b, c, d, true); }-->

  <script src="/scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

When I use "step into next functional call" from `new Vue(..)`:
[image]

**main.js**
- I noticed that nunjucks was using the `{{ }}` mustache tokens in my gulp build so I made sure in the Vue instance to change the delimiter to `<< >>` for now. Confirmed that they do show up in the .tmp folder where the app is served.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
var example1 = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['<<', '>>'],
    el: '#example-1',
    data: {
      items: [{
          message: 'Foo'
        },
        {
          message: 'Bar'
        }
      ]
    }
  });
```

**html**

```
<body>
  <ul id="example-1">
    <li v-for="item in items">
      << item.message >>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <script src="/scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**gulp file**

- The HTML rendered output is done by task `nunjucksHtml`.
- The JS is bundled by task `scripts`.
- I don't see anything wrong with browsersync, but it's one of the only differences between the local IIS site with static html and js that works.

```
const { src, dest, watch, series, parallel } = require("gulp");
const gulpLoadPlugins = require("gulp-load-plugins");
const browserSync = require("browser-sync");
const del = require("del");
const { argv } = require("yargs");

const $ = gulpLoadPlugins();
const server = browserSync.create();

const port = argv.port || 9000;
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const isDev = !isProd;

const babelRollup = require("rollup-plugin-babel");
const resolve = require('rollup-plugin-node-resolve');
const commonjs = require('rollup-plugin-commonjs');
const vue = require('rollup-plugin-vue');
const rollupReplace = require('rollup-plugin-replace');

// (other bundles not shown)
const jsBundles = [{
    src: 'app/scripts/main.js',
    dest: '.tmp/scripts',
    prodDest: 'dist/scripts'
  }
];

function scripts(done) {
  jsBundles.forEach((obj) => {
    return src(obj.src)
      .pipe($.plumber())
      .pipe($.if(!isProd, $.sourcemaps.init()))
      .pipe(
        $.betterRollup({
          plugins: [
            vue({ css: false }),
            rollupReplace({
              'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }),
            resolve({ browser: true }),
            babelRollup({
              exclude: 'node_modules/**'
            }),
            commonjs()
          ]
        }, 
        {
          format: "umd",
        })
      )
      .pipe($.if(!isProd, $.sourcemaps.write(".")))
      .pipe($.if(!isProd, dest(obj.dest), dest(obj.prodDest)))
      .pipe($.if(!isProd, server.reload({
        stream: true
      })));
  });

  done();
}

function nunjucksHtml() {
  return src("app/**/[^_]*.html")
    .pipe(
      $.nunjucksRender({
        path: ["app/"]
      })
    )
    .pipe(dest(".tmp"));
}

function clean() {
  return del([".tmp", "dist"]);
}

function startAppServer() {
  server.init({
    notify: false,
    port,
    server: {
      baseDir: [".tmp", "app"],
      routes: {
        "/node_modules": "node_modules",
      },
    },
  });

  watch([".tmp/*.html", "app/images/**/*"]).on(
    "change",
    server.reload
  );

  watch("app/**/*.html", nunjucksHtml);
  watch("app/scripts/**/*.js", scripts);
}

let serve = series(
    clean,
    parallel(nunjucksHtml, scripts),
    startAppServer
);

exports.serve = serve;
```

**package.json** (minus extras)

```
{
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-better-rollup": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-nunjucks-render": "^2.2.3",
    "rollup": "^1.16.7",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.3.3",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-vue": "^5.0.1",
    "rollup-stream": "^1.24.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "yargs": "12.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp serve"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "Firefox ESR"
  ]
}
```

**What I've tried**

- set up the example [codepen](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/50wL7mdz/) and hosted it locally with IIS and static html with inline javascript, which works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a two part issue:

1. `nunjucks render` was initially resolving `{{ property }}` and erasing it completely. To get around this I changed the variable syntax of nunjucks:

```
    .pipe(
      $.nunjucksRender({
        envOptions: {
          tags: {
            variableStart: '{#',
            variableEnd: '#}'
          }
        }
      })
    )
```

2. `import` of Vue will by default load the runtime-only module because it is declared in the `modules` portion of vue/package.json, and according to the installation docs:

> If you need to compile templates on the client (e.g. passing a string
>   to the template option, or mounting to an element using its in-DOM
>   HTML as the template), you will need the compiler and thus the full
>   build

Therefore my import ended up looking like: `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'`

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to change all the tags, just use {% raw %} tag, for example:

```
{% raw %}
  <div>
   <div>{{value}}</div>
  </div>
{% endraw %}
```